# Convert code that uses Linq to code that does not

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, attributes, .net-2.0

The following code snippet returns an array of `PropertyInfo` objects that have a defined attribute:

```
var props = t.GetProperties().Where(
                         prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(MyAttribute)));
```

.
.
How can I do the same thing in **.NET2.0**, and therefore ***without*** using Linq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
List<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo> ();

foreach (PropertyInfo prop in t.GetProperties())
{
    if ( Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(MyAttribute)) )
         props.Add (prop);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Array` and `List<T>` classes give you a lot of the same functionality as LINQ. For this one, I'd probably go with:

```
PropertyInfo[] props = Array.FindAll(t.GetProperties(), 
    delegate(PropertyInfo p) { 
        return Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(SerializableAttribute));
    });
```

or

```
List<PropertyInfo> props2 = new List<PropertyInfo>(t.GetProperties()).FindAll(
    delegate(PropertyInfo p) {
        return Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(SerializableAttribute));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [LinqBridge](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/) for such a task. LINQ is a compile time feature of C#, not a .net runtime feature. Thus you can replicate the library in .net 2.0 while still using the C# 3.0 compiler.

If you insist though:

```
List<PropertyInfo> l = new List<PropertyInfo>();

foreach(PropertyInfo prop in t.GetProperties())
{
  if(Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(MyAttribute))
    l.Add(prop);
}
```

Comment: @Femaref: Yeah, have seen that, but I would like to do this without using a library. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Why do you want to do it without a library?

Comment: @Femaref: This is such a simple example, that adding a library would be overkill. Hopefully soon I can move my app onto .NET4.0 and it won't be a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use ReSharper:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

it can do it for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks, but I am using C# Express, so no ReSharper for me unfortunately.